Set Featured Image Grab Image ID or Image File Name
Is there way of to grabbing "Image ID" or "Image File Name" after attaching a featured image (post-thumbnail) to page?
I am looking to capture that ID so that I can validate the image before posting the page.
I am using wp_insert_post_data for validation and unfortunately, it does not validate the newly attached images. If I had the ID, I can.
I am stumped on how to retrieve it and add it to input field. Any advice, much appreciated.

in the filter wp_insert_post_data, the picture id is in $postarr["_thumbnail_id"].

Holy moly. Can't believe I missed that. There is a lot of post data and it was buried at the very end. Yikes. Thank You!
